# How do I solve this linear differential equation analytically, where the system matrix is non-commutative and time dependent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a solution to the equation described below analytically:

$\dot{P}=FP+PF^T+MQM^T$

where F is a 6x6 jacobian matrix that is time dependent and and non-commutative. F is not symmetric or diagonal. M and Q are constants. P is a 6x6 matrix. Is it possible to find a solution? Please do not comment on finding a numerical solution; I already know how to do that.

Comment: if $P$ is 6x1 and $F$ is 6x6, then $PF^T$ makes no sense

Comment: What do you mean that $F$ is a jacobian matrix? What do you mean that $F$ is noncommutative?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "analytically," and also on what the question exactly is, the answer should be a variation on a Dyson series or Magnus series.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I have edited my question. P is a 6x6 matrix. It is basically a covariance matrix.

Comment: @BenMcKay I have a state vector with 6 elements. Also, there are 6 differential equations giving the rate of change of these 6 elements. F is the jacobian matrix corresponding to those differential equations and states. F is non-commutative means that $F(t_1)F(t_2)\neq F(t_2)F(t_1)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I will check what those series are, and get back to you. It would be awesome if you can refer a source as well for these series-es.

Comment: Only possible via an infinite series, and except for VERY special cases, completely useless for all purposes.

Comment: @nonlinearism Can you please elaborate on what sorts of infinite series you are talking about, or, how exactly do I approach this problem using infinite series? Any external link or source would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dyson/magnus series as already mentioned by Qiaochu.

Comment: @nonlinearism thanks! I figured it out now.

Answer (score 3):

Use [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Setting $p=\operatorname{vec}(P)$, your system can be rewritten as
$$
\dot{p} = Ap+b,
$$
with $A = I \otimes F + F\otimes I$, $b=\operatorname{vec}(MQM^T)$.

Now your problem is a [classical one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Systems_of_linear_differential_equations) (first-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients). Unfortunately, no closed-form solution exists in general, if $F$ is time-dependent --- apart from simple cases in which all $F(t)$ commute.

Comment: what is this cross within circle symbol? Also, does vec have any special meaning here?

Comment: @smritinandanpaul Follow those links. :)

Comment: thanks!! I will get back if I get stuck.